# stopping href=javascript:void(0) event from firing in IE6. Telerik NumericTextBox issue

Tags: javascript, telerik, internet-explorer-6

I am using the radnumerictextbox control with Spin Buttons which output HTML with href="javascrupt:void(0)". I am setting a ValueChanging event via the ClientEvents-OnValueChanging property of the control.

All works fine, except in IE6, the ValueChanging  event fires and then a new window opens with Javascript:void(0) in the address bar.

If I add an alert("whatever") to the end of my ValueChanging function then OKing this stops the window from opening, but I cant find any unobtrusive way to override the new window.

Any ideas?

Cheers

Stewart

Comment: could you show your not working code...

Comment: Write `javascript`, not `javascrupt`.

Answer (score 0):

You could try adding **return false;** on your ValueChanging function or after your OnValueChanging function in radnumerictextbox control